# Should I use the ref or out keyword here?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I have an object that may be null, which I will pass to a method that will set its properties.

So my code looks like:

```
User user = null;  // may or may not be null at this point.

SetUserProperties(user);

UpdateUser(user);


public void SetUserProperties(User user)
{
      if(user == null) 
          user = new User();

     user.Firstname = "blah";
     ....

}
```

So I am updating the same object I pass into SetUserProperties.

Should I use the 'ref' keyword in my method SetUserProperties?

Answer (score 5):

I think that 'ref' fits the semantics of what you are trying to do here better.

I, however, try to avoid the 'out' and 'ref' keywords if possible.

Does this suit your needs?  It doesn't use either and is a little bit more clear in what it is doing, IMO.

```
user = user ?? new User();

SetUserProperties(user);

UpdateUser(user);
```

Comment: Yes, but user's properties (that were updated in SetUserProperties) will be out of scope in UpdateUser(user) right?

Comment: @Blankman: No - because they'll be on the same object. The value of `user` is just a reference. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 5):

It's important to be aware of the difference between an *object* and a *variable*:

- You want the caller's variable to be updated to refer to a new object in some cases, so you need *pass by reference* semantics. That means you need `ref` or `out`
- You need to read the *existing* value of the variable to know whether to create a new object or not. That means you need `ref` rather than `out`. If you changed it to an `out` parameter, your `if` statement wouldn't compile, because `user` wouldn't be definitely assigned at the start of the method.

Personally I'm not sure this is a nice design, however. Are you *sure* that it makes sense for the method to create the new object? Can you not do that at the call site? It feels slightly awkward as it is.

Another alternative to using `ref` (but still potentially creating a new user within the method) would be to return the appropriate reference:

```
user = SetUserProperties(user);

...

public User SetUserProperties(User user)
{
    if(user == null) 
    {
        user = new User();
    }
    user.Firstname = "blah";
    ....
    return user;
}
```

Comment: my method is actually returning boolean already, that is the problem.

Comment: @Blankman: And that's why it's best to give us as realistic a picture as possible in the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would use ref since you have the *potential* to point the variable to a new object in memory. If you used out, you would be *required* to change user.

Answer (score 0):

`ref` = You want to have the function have a handle to the object, and *potentially* "redirect it to another location in memory" (i.e. set it to a different instantiation of that object type)

`out` = You *require* the method to "redirect it to another location in memory"

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should use `ref`. The `out` keyword is for uninitialized variables, which isn't the case here.