# Should I use the ref keyword here?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, ref

I'm new to C# so I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555538/should-i-use-the-ref-or-out-keyword-here) question but I'm still not sure whether I should be including the **ref** keyword here when marshalling the second parameter of the GetWindoInfo() Win32 API call using p/invoke:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowInfo", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref tagWINDOWINFO pwi);
```

From the MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for **ref**:

> The ref keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by
>   value.

So in that case my code above seems to be correct, right? Would changing the marshalling clause to instead marshal an UnmanagedType.LPStruct and removing the **ref** keyword result in the same thing? Like so:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowInfo", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] tagWINDOWINFO pwi);
```

From the MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633516(v=vs.85).aspx) for **GetWindowInfo function**:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetWindowInfo(
  _In_    HWND        hwnd,
  _Inout_ PWINDOWINFO pwi
);
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments to the answer, the first code example is correct. The second code block is incorrect because passing by pointer and passing by reference are different and reflect a fundamental misunderstanding on my part. I was thinking of C++ dereferencing. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430112/what-is-the-difference-between-a-c-sharp-reference-and-a-pointer) question for more.

Comment: I read the first part of your question "I'm new to C#..." and looked at your example code then thought to myself, "maybe Windows API isn't the best place to start". I then saw you had experience with C++ and realized you weren't new to programming, just C#. Carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use the `ref` keyword for the struct.

First, there's a really great resource for P/Invoke definitions that you can find at www.pinvoke.net - and the particular method you're dealing with is documented here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowinfo.  You'll see that it's defined using the `ref` keyword.  This makes sense when you consider that the method is documented as `_Inout_` for that parameter in the MSDN docs you linked.

The reason for this is that the `ref` keyword will allow that reference to be passed and have the struct you're dealing with before calling the method get updated/modified - rather than passing it in as is and never getting to see what the method actually does to it.   In other words, without the `ref` keyword, your code would never see changes to the `struct` made within the `GetWindowInfo` call - `GetWindowInfo` would be working with its "own" copy of that structure.

If you want to read a bit more about why your second version wouldn't work, check out JaredPar's great explanation to [What is the difference between a C# Reference and a Pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430112/what-is-the-difference-between-a-c-sharp-reference-and-a-pointer)

Comment: Hey thanks for the first answer to my first ever SO question! Yes I know about pinvoke.net and I already use their extension in VS2015.

So when you said Yes, did you mean that my code is correct or that the second way of implementing it will also work?

Comment: Sorry, edited to clarify - yes, you should use `ref`.

Comment: Just to clarify, in my second code example I changed the marshalling so that instead of marshalling an unmanaged struct and thereby needing to use the ref keyword, I simply marshalled an unmanaged struct pointer.

Are my two code examples essentially the same thing is what I am asking?

Comment: Passing an pointer and passing a by reference are different - so no, that wouldn't work

Comment: I've added a link to another question that explains a bit more in depth about the difference between passing by ref or using a pointer

Comment: Thanks again Dan, turns out JaredPar's explanation at the link you gave is **exactly** what I was looking for.